# CSS 'lookbehind' using sass / less

Tags: css, sass, less, modernizr

I am currently using sass to help structure my CSS. A trivial given below.

```
.container {
    .list {
        .selected {
            background-image : url('highlighted.png');
        }
    }
}
```

However I am also using modernizr (http://modernizr.com/docs/)  and want to utilise CSS3 where possible. In this example I want to test for availability of `border-radius` , and use `border-radius` rather than a background image. Therefore I need to check for the presence of `borderradius` class on the `html` element. Is it possible to achieve this using some sort of look behind? Or do I have to repeat the code again with the `.borderradius` class, the end result being the following :

```
.container {
    .list {
        .selected {
            background-image : url('highlighted.png');
        }
    }
}

.borderradius .container {
    .list {
        .selected {
            background : yellow;
            border-radius : 10px;
        }
    }
}
```

To me this looks messy and difficult to maintain in a large project. Does anyone have a more elegant ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can reference parent selectors using the ampersand (&), like this:

```
.container {
    .list {
        .selected {
            background-image : url('highlighted.png');
            .borderradius & {
                background : yellow;
                border-radius : 10px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which will compile to:

```
.container .list .selected { 
    background-image : url('highlighted.png');
}

.borderradius .container .list .selected {
    background : yellow;
    border-radius : 10px;
}
```

Check out [this article](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand), or [this one](http://joeloliveira.com/2011/06/28/the-ampersand-a-killer-sass-feature/) for a more in-depth explanation of how useful this can be:

> ...you can place a trailing ampersand (&) character at the end of your selector declaration in place of the repeating selector, and sit back and enjoy the awesomeness of Sass

Comment: Thanks, what does the & signify here? Any element further up the tree?

Comment: The '&' tells SASS to pull the entire parent selector into wherever you place it. So, in this example it becomes '.container .list .selected'